# Converting google map api coordinates into meters

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, raster

How would I go about converting the results of my map bounding box into meters within javascript?

For example, if I have the coordinates 51.52366625446907, -0.07467269897460938 decimal degrees, can I project that into something like 555000 155000 meters?

(If it is easier, I could try to export my raster from ArcGIS in decimal degree format; I don't know which option would be better).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i would use http://proj4js.org/

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. It's a really useful library!

Answer (score 1):

You could call the [Project Geometries](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/project.html) operation on [an ArcGIS Geometry Server](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project).