# Using the Proj4js library to convert from Google Maps to projected values

Tags: google-maps, javascript, coordinate-system

I'm using the [proj4s](http://proj4js.org/) javascript library (based on advice from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/converting-google-map-api-coordinates-into-meters) I asked previously) to convert lat/long values on my webpage. This page receives the lat/long values from google maps and converts them to the British National Grid (ORD SURV GB), which wikipedia tells me has the following code: EPSG:27700. I want to calculate the maximum and minimum values of both the latitude and longitude, so I can query a database.

My code is as follows:

```
var source = new Proj4js.Proj('WGS84');    
var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:27700');

bounds = map.getBounds()  // Get bounds of map after user pans around   
zoom = map.getZoom()      // Get zoom level

xMax = bounds.getNorthEast().lat()  //get max and min values for lat/long
yMax = bounds.getNorthEast().lng()  
xMin = bounds.getSouthWest().lat()
yMin = bounds.getSouthWest().lng()

alert('xMin: ' + xMin + '\nxMax: ' + xMax)
alert('yMin: ' + yMin + '\nyMax: ' + yMax)          

// transforming point coordinates   
var latXNew = new Proj4js.Point( xMin, xMax );   
var latYNew = new Proj4js.Point( yMin, yMax ); 

Proj4js.transform(source, dest, latXNew);      
Proj4js.transform(source, dest, latYNew);
```

However, I'm not getting the correct results from my webpage. I've loaded in a kml file that has a rectangle with boundaries that I know, and the values don't match up. They appear to be off by at least a factor of approximately 8.

```
NE Lat: 52.25635981528854
NE Lng: 1.3534606328125243

Expected Lat: 500000.0
Expected Lng: 150000.0

Returned Lat: -5527596.989640327 (incorrect)
Returned Lng: 622727.1071581601 (incorrect)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Perhaps you have mixed up the latitude and longitude.  I would be *sure* this is the case if your "returned lng" were exactly ten times larger than you report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you're converting the correct value when performing the transformation.

You're creating new Points using the same axis.  Try this:

```
// transforming point coordinates   
var southWestOld = new Proj4js.Point( xMin, yMin );   
var northEastOld = new Proj4js.Point( xMax, yMax ); 

var southWestNew = Proj4js.transform(source, dest, southWestOld);      
var northEastNew = Proj4js.transform(source, dest, northEastOld);
```

Also, speaking convention is to say "x,y" or "lat,long" but the x coordinate is usually Easting (longitude) and y is usually Northing (latitude).

If using the right coordinates still does not produce the expected result, try switching lat and long and see if your numbers land where you expect.

For the following code I am not getting the values you expect, but I am getting values that agree with the calculator found here: http://www.nearby.org.uk/tests/GeoTools.html

```
Proj4js.defs["WGS84"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";

var source = new Proj4js.Proj('WGS84');    
var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:27700');

var testPt = new Proj4js.Point(1.3534606328125,52.25635981528);

Proj4js.transform(source, dest, testPt);
```

My result coordinate is `628970.515543512,267319.1785250341`, and the one from the website is `TM 28971 67319`.

Comment: Good point - I was not aware of that. However, I'm still not getting values that are correct even considering that.

Comment: Please add some sample input/output values to the question.

Comment: I just added some.

Answer (score 2):

epsg:2770 in your question and 27770 in your code are 2 different values.

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2770/

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/

Make sure you're using the right one.  From your question it seems that 27770 is the right one to use (second link).

Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";

Comment: Thanks @Vadim, i have edited my question to include that. You are correct that I wrote the wrong one in my text.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that your source projection is right? Google Maps is usually in epsg:900913.

Comment: I'm not sure at all, so I will try that. Googling (!) for it has given me a lot of different suggestions.

Comment: EPSG:900913 parameters

Comment: I tried using http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6627/ and it still is not returning correct values.

Comment: celenius: you can't just guess! - what do the values of your source bounding box look like?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound so casual; I looked on Spatial Reference for EPSG:900913, and it is defined there as 'SR-ORG:6627'. I used that for my source (defined in the webpage) amd similarly 'epsg:2770' for destination. I compared the values and they are different. For example, my webpage returns Xmin: 622726.0903127209, Ymin: 622726.0903127209 while my values should be Xmin: 500000, Ymin: 150000

Comment: I was wondering more about the source coords - if the xmin is between -5 and 5 it is 4326 (or other geographic projection) if it is -50000 and 50000 (or so) then it is in meters and 900913 is appropriate.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean about what the values should be between (-5 and 5), for example. Looking at the bounding box in ArcGIS I have the following information: Projected Coordinate System: `British National Grid (ORD SURV GB)
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
false_easting: 400000.00000000
false_northing: -100000.00000000
central_meridian: -2.00000000
scale_factor: 0.99960127
latitude_of_origin: 49.00000000
Linear Unit:  Meter` The box is around London, and has the coordinates (500000, 150000) for southwest corner, and (560000, 210000) in the northeast corner.

Comment: You need to determine what the input data projection is. If your input data is in OSGB (27700) then you don't need to reproject it. Other wise you need to determine if your data is in 4326 (small numbers) or google (900913) (big numbers), then you need to use one or the other epsg code in your proj4js code.

Comment: I'm certain that the input projection data is in the British National Grid which I believe is EPSG:27700. However, when it is laid ontop of google maps I assumed I should use their lat/long values, projected, to convert it back into the original British National grid format. Is this correct?

Comment: To clarify though, I export this using ArcGIS' 'Export to KML function', which I now assume turns it into epsg:900913

Answer (score 0):

EPSG:4326 is built in. Note the order, its [x,y], so [lon,lat]

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:27700", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs");
    
proj4('EPSG:27700','EPSG:4326').forward( [480069, 186342] ).reverse(); 
// [51.57027349352602, -0.8461130514492281]
            
proj4('EPSG:27700','EPSG:4326').inverse( [ -0.846, 51.57 ] ); // lon, lat !!! 
// [480077.3157135821, 186311.70711789717]
```