# Basic proj4 conversion UTM grid -> longlat and back

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, datum

I'm a GIS novice, and am struggling to understand how to drive proj4 to accomplish what seems like a simple thing. I've googled for a couple of days, but everything I find seems to presuppose quite advanced knowledge, and leaves many things unsaid. Stack Overflow couldn't clear it up for me, either..

I have a conversion between UTM easting/northing and lat/long to do in both directions. Once I get this working, I'll add some different projections/datums.

I'm working on my recently acquired knowledge/assumptions:

1. This conversion will require a datum translation, because WGS84 (standard datum for UTM) has it's prime meridian approximately 100m east of Greenwich (where longitude is zero).
2. I don't need to worry about ellipsoids, because the lat/long are *geographic* coordinates, rather than projected ones.
3. I can either start the conversions using one string (as used in the command-line instantiation), or can pre-assemble a source and destination object, and call `pj_fwd(data, ref)` directly.

Another issue is that if I call the code directly, while I've found the `projUV` datatype - I can't find the corresponding UTM version.

Could someone *please* get me started with the format of the string(s) of either method required?

Perhaps using conversion from zone 56 499451mE 6960921mS to lat/long as an example.

Comment: I asked a question about this a little while ago: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/using-the-proj4js-library-to-convert-from-google-maps-to-projected-values It uses javascript but maybe the discussion is helpful

Comment: Do you need to perform this calculation client-side? If not, you could use an approach akin to http://rapidiphonedev.com/?p=16

Comment: You generally don't need to worry about 1. A 'Greenwich' prime meridian means the current zero point somewhere in the vicinity of the Greenwich observatory, not the original location. I'm not sure about 2. Lat/lon values need to have a geographic coordinate [reference] system definition aka datum attached to them. On their own, they are not a unique identifier. If you need to use different GeoCRS or different UTM zones based on different GeoCRS, then, yes, you'll need to handle datum transformations. The UTM coords you quoted could be based on WGS84, GDA94, AGD66, AGD84, etc.

Comment: That's disappointing about lat/long needing a datum - That was the only thing I was confident about! (Greenwich was 0 Longitude, and 1/2 way between Geographic north and south was 0 latitude). Bummer.
Thanks for the help

Comment: The utm package (pip install utm) works great for this purpose, and is easy to use: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) project, they seem to have some working examples of wrapping Proj.4 on the iOS platform in Objective-C. The actual transformation looks to happen in [Mapview/Map/RMProjection.m](https://github.com/route-me/route-me/blob/master/MapView/Map/RMProjection.m).

Comment: I'll upvote this answer as soon as I have enough reputation - Thanks for the link, I didn't know that existed..

Comment: I made this the answer, as although it didn't answer the question, it proposed another method that will work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd use the Python bindings for the Proj4 library - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj/1.8.6

Further details at http://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

You can pass your projection parameters directly to the projection object as follows:

```
PROJ_32756 = """
+proj=utm +zone=56 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
"""
p1 = pyproj.Proj(PROJ_32756)
```

A full list of these strings can be found at http://spatialreference.org/
For zone 56 see http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32756/proj4/

Many of these projections are already built into the library so you can just pass in the code. Below is an example of reprojecting some geojson from one projection to another. You should be able to adapt to your needs.

```
import pyproj
import simplejson

p1 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857')
p2 =pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:29902')

json='{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-972279.15280781,6907135.0149664],[-995516.00940234,6867999.2564914],[-946596.31130859,6844762.3998969],[-964941.19809375,6892459.1055383],[-972279.15280781,6907135.0149664]]]}'

pydata = simplejson.loads(json)
print str(pydata)
new_coords = []
for p in pydata['coordinates'][0]:
    x2, y2 = pyproj.transform(p1,p2,p[0],p[1])
    new_coords.append([x2, y2])

new_json = simplejson.dumps(dict(type="Polygon", coordinates=[new_coords], srid="29902"))
print str(new_json)
```

Comment: Thanks geographika - I wish I _could_ use python, as there seems to be a few examples out there for doing so, but I'm constrained to objective-c (and so also c++ or c). I downloaded the C source, and just need to tap into that, somehow..
The documentation for the python bindings seems several orders of magnitude more helpful than that of the proj4 library itself..
If I had more reputation, I'd +1 you for the suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok..iPhone development by any chance? Maybe the unit tests in the source are your best examples - http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/browser/trunk/proj/nad/testvarious ?